# WPF DataGrid binding custom row header give me suggestion 

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, togglebutton

I am trying to do togglebutton visiblity change on true/false properties,
my togglebutton in row header template,
I also create convert for change properties.

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=col1, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=DemoConvertor}}"
```

refer this like:
https://skydrive.live.com/P.mvc#!/selectembed.aspx/.Public/dgRowToggleButtonSample.zip?ref=11&cid=0c0b4f9d80b744cd&sc=documents

Comment: Can you please specify what exctly is the issue?

Comment: when my data grid loading complete then,i need the toggle button on specific row ,not in all row.my toggle button in row header template ,how can i hide the visibility.